# Elastic Search Script Regex Aggregation

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, scripting, aggregation

I would like to know how can I use regex in a script. Example:

```
"aggs": {
   "inventary": {
      "sum": {
         "script": "(doc['action'].value == /^request/) ? 1 : 0"
      }
   }
}
```

So I would like to match every `action` who matches with `request*`

It is possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you simply need to use `==~` instead of `==`

```
"aggs": {
   "inventary": {
      "sum": {
         "script": "(doc.action.value ==~ /^request/) ? 1 : 0"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked :). But the Regex should match all string so I changed it to `/^request(.*)/`